# checking if $tdHide.val() is empty, dont set .prop('name')

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my code :
I want to have checking like if `$tdHide.val()` is equal to empty string, i dont want the commented area to set name or trigger.

```
  $('.save').on("click",function(){    
      var table = $('#myTable');
       table.find('tr').each(
       function(i){
         var $tds = $(this).find('td input');
         var $tdHide = $(this).find('td input[\'hidden\']');
         var $tdselect = $(this).find('td select');
          if($tdHide.val() == ""){
         /*  $tds.eq(2).prop('name','lang_cd'+ctr);
           $tds.eq(3).prop('name','descr'+ctr);
           $tdslect.prop('name','support'+ctr);
           $tds.eq(4).prop('name','flag'+ctr);
          */
           ctr++;
          }
  });
```

Comment: Any reason to not use an [`if`-statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else)? This basic flow control is covered in tutorials.

Comment: @user2864740, no sir, dont have to use `if statement` , just using it to explain sir

Comment: So then *use* an `if` to control the logic.

Answer (score 1):

Just make an `if ($tdHide.val())`, it will be executed only if the value is not equal to an empty string.

```
 $('.save').on("click",function(){    
          var table = $('#myTable');
           table.find('tr').each(
           function(i){
             var $tds = $(this).find('td input');
             var $tdHide = $(this).find('td input[\'hidden\']');
             var $tdselect = $(this).find('td select');
             if ($tdHide.val()) {
               $tds.eq(2).prop('name','lang_cd'+ctr);
               $tds.eq(3).prop('name','descr'+ctr);
               $tdslect.prop('name','support'+ctr);
               $tds.eq(4).prop('name','flag'+ctr);
             }
               ctr++;
            });
```